# why checkbox is hidden even using my htmlhelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, html-helper

I've read a lot of links about hidden filed bout checkbox I've decided use custom htmlhelper but at the moment, I can't see checkbox in my page when I remove checkbox word in `type="checkbox"` it's shown as a textbox I think it's sensitive about type of control that is name checkbox.

**Update :**
I didn't have any input filed with hidden value
[**Picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIvi0.jpg)

```
 public static class HelperUI
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxSimpleFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        string checkBoxWithHidden = htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString().Trim();
        string pureCheckBox = checkBoxWithHidden.Substring(0, checkBoxWithHidden.IndexOf("<input", 1));
        return new MvcHtmlString(pureCheckBox);
    }
}


 <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group row">
         <label class="text-right col-md-3">وضعیت</label>

         <div class="col-md-9">

             @Html.CheckBoxSimpleFor(model => model.Status, new { @class = "form-control filled-in" })


         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `position: absolute; left: -9999px; opacity: 0`

Comment: That CSS snippet is the reason you *can't* see your checkbox. It's off screen and has an opacity of zero. You can see that CSS is active if you look at the CSS inspector in the developer tools.

Comment: @serpent5,yes exactly it works for me but I changed styles a little bit.     'position: unset !important;'
 'opacity: 1 !important;'

Answer (score 0):

Hi @joe if you using bootstrap for html designing, then the checkbox will be shows as hidden because of bootstrap checkbox html sysntax or designing is different make change as per it

```
  <div class="checkbox">
     <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
     <label for="checkbox1">
      Default
  </label>
       </div>
```

this is the checkbox designing sysntax or code in bootstrap, so you need to make change as per

```
    <div class="checkbox col-md-9">
         @Html.CheckBoxSimpleFor(model => model.Status, new { @class = " filled-in" })
    </div>
```